# How do I move and replace the arrow from a drop down menu with Foundation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

the default drop down menu item appears with a default arrow on the right. I want my custom arrow (image) to appear on the bottom. What part of the CSS would I need to modify to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using classic Top Bar navigation in Foundation, you should have the following css. Just replace `position: absolute;` and adjust your margins.

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a::after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border: inset 5px;
   border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) transparent transparent transparent;
   border-top-style: solid;
   margin-top: -2.5px; /* Adjust to your need */
   top: 22.5px; /* Remove it */
   margin-right: 15px; /* Adjust to your need */
   position: absolute; /* Remove it */
   right: 0; /* Remove it */
}
```